# I can't get my remote deployment working on Digital Ocean

Tags: git, github, deployment, digital-ocean

I was following [this tutorial](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-automatic-deployment-with-git-with-a-vps) on Digital Ocean to try deployment for my code remotely. The scenario I want to apply is to develop my code on my machine and once I push the updates it directly changes to production state and views the results.

It all went fine till the last step that connects my machine code to the repo; I commit changes to and it keep giving me that error.

```
 Permission denied (publickey).
 fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
  Please make sure you have the correct access rights
  and the repository exists.
```

and I keep the public key in this directory:

```
/home/myuser/.ssh
```

The following screenshot explains more:

[image]

So what did I miss in this tutorial?

Comment: It looks like you received some very helpful advice below. How did you get on with it?

Answer (score 1):

Please consider copying-and-pasting text into your question rather than images representing text. It makes it easier for us to parse the question, copy text from your example and is better for posterity.

I think (!) one issue is that you are referencing the Droplet by its hostname (`ubuntu-s-1vcpu-3gb-fra1-01`) from another (!?) machine where this name is not defined.

Error:

```
ssh: Could not resolve hostname ubuntu-s-1vcpu-3gb-fra1-01
```

You may prove this to yourself by pinging or looking up this hostname from your machine:

```sh
DROPLET="ubuntu-s-1vcpu-3gb-fra1-01"

ping ${DROPLET}
nslookup ${DROPLET}
dig ${DROPLET}
```

NB: all these will fail proving that your machine can't resolve the Droplet by its hostname

You have options:

- Either reference the machine by its public (global) IP address instead;
- Or add this hostname and IP so that your local machine can resolve it;
- Or add this hostname to a DNS domain that you own so that any host can resolve it